# Can I send different mails to different receivers with different messages

Tags: python, smtp

I'm trying to send emails with different messages to different receivers via libsmtp and gmail in a loop.

I tried to send mail without closing smtp connection. It just send all message to same receiver but I would like to send messages with receivers.
I tried to open and quit connection for each loop but after first iteration executes and quits the connection, second iteration gives error message "smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first" even though it should have connect again.

```py
class Mail:
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    def __init__(self, addr_from, addr_to):
        self.msg['From'] = addr_from
        self.msg['To'] = addr_to
    def set_subject(self, subject):
        self.msg['Subject'] = subject
    def set_message(self, message):
        self.msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
    def attach_image(self, image_location, image_name):
        fp = open(image_location, 'rb')
        img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
        img.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % image_name)
        fp.close()
        self.msg.attach(img)
    def get_mail(self):
        return self.msg



class EmailServer:
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    def __init__(self, sender_mail, password):
        self.sender_mail = sender_mail
        self.password = password
        self.server.ehlo()
        self.server.starttls()
        self.server.login(sender_mail, password)

    def send_mail(self, mail):
        self.server.sendmail(mail['From'], mail['To'], mail.as_string())

    def quit_server(self):
        self.server.quit()

for row in range(0,x):

    name = sheet.cell_value(row, 0)
    mail_adress = sheet.cell_value(row, 1)

    print(name, mail_adress)

    mail = Mail('xxxxxxxx@gmail.com', mail_adress)
    mail.set_subject("subject")
    mail.set_message('message')
    server = EmailServer('xxxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxxxxxx')
    mail.attach_image('/Users/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx.jpg', 'title')
    server.send_mail(mail.get_mail())
    server.quit_server()
```

Comment: Write a script with just the for loop suite statements after the *print* and the `mail_address` *hard coded* does it work? Then copy and paste that changing the `mail_address`  in the second set of statements. Does that send mail to the two recipients?

Comment: I figured out where the problem is but couldn't understand why self.msg['To'] = addr_to part in Mail's init function do not change the value and somehow it has previous email adress. Isn't it newly create the object in every iteration? How does it remember? If it remembers somehow why does it not change the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you defined `Mail`, `msg` is a class attribute so each instance of `Mail` *contains* the same `msg`.

```
import email
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

class Mail:
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    def __init__(self, addr_from, addr_to):
        self.msg['From'] = addr_from
        self.msg['To'] = addr_to

for afrom, ato in zip(list('abcd'),list('wert')):
    mail = Mail(afrom, ato)
    print(id(mail.msg))

In [60]: 
160675264
160675264
160675264
160675264
```

MIMEMultipart is an `email.message` object; its [`__setitem__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/email/message.py#L393) docstring states:  `...does not overwrite an existing header with the same field name.  Use __delitem__() first to delete any existing headers.` ...

```
In [61]: help(mail.msg.__setitem__)
Help on method __setitem__ in module email.message:

__setitem__(name, val) method of email.mime.multipart.MIMEMultipart instance
    Set the value of a header.

    Note: this does not overwrite an existing header with the same field
    name.  Use __delitem__() first to delete any existing headers.
```

After the for loop, the `From` and `To` headers are lists with multiple values:

```
mail.msg.get_all('From'), mail.msg.get_all('To')
Out[62]: (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['w', 'e', 'r', 't'])
```

---

One solution to your problem would be to delete the `From` and `To` headers before assigning a new value in the loop.

```
In [63]: del mail.msg['From']

In [64]: del mail.msg['To']

In [65]: mail.msg.get_all('From'), mail.msg.get_all('To')
Out[65]: (None, None)

In [66]: mail.msg['From'] = 'z'

In [67]: mail.msg['To'] = 'y'

In [68]: mail.msg.get_all('From'), mail.msg.get_all('To')
Out[68]: (['z'], ['y'])
```

---

Another option might be to create a new `msg` for each `Mail` instance.

```
class Mail:
    def __init__(self, addr_from, addr_to):
        self.msg = MIMEMultipart()
        self.msg['From'] = addr_from
        self.msg['To'] = addr_to
```

---

Another option would be to send the mail AFTER the loop. `SMTP.sendmail`'s [`to_addrs` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html?highlight=smtp#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail) accepts a list so `EmailServer.sendmail` needs to be modified

```
class EmailServer:
    ...
    ...

    def send_mail(self, mail):
        self.server.sendmail(mail['From'], mail.get_all('To'), mail.as_string())
```

Then After a loop that adds multiple `'To'` addresses

```
server.send_mail(mail.get_mail())
server.quit_server()
```

I'm not able to test this one but it should work. You should probably create just one `Mail` instance with all the *stuff* that doesn't change; and one `EmailServer` instance then use the loop to add multiple address to the `Mail` instance. Then send the mail.

Comment: You figure out my 2 weeks fear. It was due to my lack of python knowledge. Problem was it was not creating new instances of multipart outside init function. Thanks!